# SharePoint 2013 - Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I have developed an app using vs 2012. When I try to deploy the app, then I am getting the below error.

Error : Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps.

I have google it and find the below link:-

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/fp161236.aspx
In this link, they are saying that Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click DNS.

But I have not find DNS or DNS Manager.

Can any one help me.